# How to delete selected items in listView by id(primary key) winforms

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

So i am making a program where i can add users to a database and then they are displayed at the bottom of the screen.
Now i also am trying to delete certain items from the database but i need the id (which is the primary key) becuase all the other fields can be duplicates and it would delete all the items where that field id duplicate (which is allowed)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient; //sql server local db

namespace KermisInschrijven
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool isChecked = radioButton1.Checked;
            string day = "";
            if (isChecked)
            {
                day = radioButton1.Text;
                load_list_zat();
            } else
            {
                day = radioButton2.Text;
                load_list_zon();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                add_entry_zat();
            } else if ( !radioButton1.Checked){
                add_entry_zon();
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item.Selected);
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("deleting");
                    item.Remove();
                    string cn_string = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Admin\\Code\\C#\\Projects\\KermisInschrijven\\dbInschrijvingen.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_string);

                    string sql_Text = "DELETE FROM tbl_zaterdag WHERE id=@num";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql_Text, cn_connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", <Insert_id_here>);
                    cn_connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (r.Read())
                    {

                    }
                    cn_connection.Close();

                    load_list_zat();
                }
            }
        }

        private void make_empty()
        {
            for (int i = listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                    listView1.Items[i].Remove();
            }
        }

        private void add_entry_zat()
        {
            string cn_string = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Admin\\Code\\C#\\Projects\\KermisInschrijven\\dbInschrijvingen.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_string);

            string first_name = firstname.Text;
            string last_name = lastname.Text;

            decimal mg = mosg.Value;
            decimal mk = mosk.Value;
            decimal mgh = mosgh.Value;
            decimal mkh = moskh.Value;
            decimal pg = pag.Value;
            decimal pk = pak.Value;
            decimal pgh = pagh.Value;
            decimal pkh = pakh.Value;

            bool payed = checkBox1.Checked;

            string sql_Text = "INSERT INTO tbl_zaterdag (voornaam, achternaam, mg, mk, mgh, mkh, pg, pk, pgh, pkh, betaald) VALUES(@first, @last, @mg, @mk, @mgh, @mkh, @pg, @pk, @pgh, @pkh, @payed)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql_Text, cn_connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", first_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", last_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mg", mg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mk", mk);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mgh", mgh);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mkh", mkh);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pg", pg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk", pk);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pgh", pgh);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pkh", pkh);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payed", payed);

            try
            {
                cn_connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read())
                {

                }
                cn_connection.Close();
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

            load_list_zat();
        }

        private void add_entry_zon()
        {
            string cn_string = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Admin\\Code\\C#\\Projects\\KermisInschrijven\\dbInschrijvingen.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_string);

            string first_name = firstname.Text;
            string last_name = lastname.Text;

            decimal mg = mosg.Value;
            decimal mk = mosk.Value;
            decimal mgh = mosgh.Value;
            decimal mkh = moskh.Value;
            decimal pg = pag.Value;
            decimal pk = pak.Value;
            decimal pgh = pagh.Value;
            decimal pkh = pakh.Value;

            bool payed = checkBox1.Checked;

            string sql_Text = "INSERT INTO tbl_zondag (voornaam, achternaam, mg, mk, mgh, mkh, pg, pk, pgh, pkh, betaald) VALUES(@first, @last, @mg, @mk, @mgh, @mkh, @pg, @pk, @pgh, @pkh, @payed)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql_Text, cn_connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", first_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", last_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mg", mg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mk", mk);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mgh", mgh);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mkh", mkh);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pg", pg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk", pk);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pgh", pgh);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pkh", pkh);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payed", payed);

            try
            {
                cn_connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read())
                {

                }
                cn_connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

            load_list_zon();
        }
        private void load_list_zat()
        {
            make_empty();
            //connection string
            string cn_string = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Admin\\Code\\C#\\Projects\\KermisInschrijven\\dbInschrijvingen.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            //connection
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn_string);

            //get data
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_zaterdag", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            //loop through items in dt
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.IndexOf(row) != 0)
                {

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row["id"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["voornaam"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["achternaam"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["mg"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["mk"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["mgh"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["mkh"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["pg"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["pk"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["pgh"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["pkh"].ToString());
                    double price = calc_price(row["mg"], row["mk"], row["mgh"], row["mkh"], row["pg"], row["pk"], row["pgh"], row["pkh"]);
                    item.SubItems.Add(price.ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["betaald"].ToString());

                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        private void load_list_zon()
        {
            make_empty();  //connection string
            string cn_string = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Admin\\Code\\C#\\Projects\\KermisInschrijven\\dbInschrijvingen.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            //connection
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn_string);

            //get data
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_zondag", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            //loop through items in dt
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row["id"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["voornaam"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["achternaam"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["mg"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["mk"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["mgh"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["mkh"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["pg"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["pk"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["pgh"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["pkh"].ToString());
                double price = calc_price(row["mg"], row["mk"], row["mgh"], row["mkh"], row["pg"], row["pk"], row["pgh"], row["pkh"]);
                item.SubItems.Add(price.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(row["betaald"].ToString());

                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private double calc_price(object mg, object mk, object mgh, object mkh, object pg, object pk, object pgh, object pkh)
        {
            string mg_str = mg.ToString();
            string mk_str = mk.ToString();
            string mgh_str = mgh.ToString();
            string mkh_str = mkh.ToString();
            string pg_str = pg.ToString();
            string pk_str = pk.ToString();
            string pgh_str = pgh.ToString();
            string pkh_str = pkh.ToString();

            double mg_int = Convert.ToDouble(mg_str);
            double mk_int = Convert.ToDouble(mk_str);
            double mgh_int = Convert.ToDouble(mgh_str);
            double mkh_int = Convert.ToDouble(mkh_str);
            double pg_int = Convert.ToDouble(pg_str);
            double pk_int = Convert.ToDouble(pk_str);
            double pgh_int = Convert.ToDouble(pgh_str);
            double pkh_int = Convert.ToDouble(pkh_str);

            double result = mg_int * 20 + mk_int * 15 + mgh_int * 10 + mkh_int * 7.5 + pg_int * 12 + pk_int * 8 + pgh_int * 6 + pkh_int * 4;
            return result;

        }
    }
}
```

My form look like this (Its in dutch if you wondered):
[image: (Its in Dutch if you wonderd)]

I am not able to find how I can get the id of the selected item(s),
In my code i want  to be replaced by the id of the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
just had to do item.Text becuase that is the selected item's name....

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item.Selected);
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("deleting");
                    item.Remove();
                    string cn_string = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Admin\\Code\\C#\\Projects\\KermisInschrijven\\dbInschrijvingen.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_string);

                    string sql_Text = "DELETE FROM tbl_zaterdag WHERE id=@num";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql_Text, cn_connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", item.Text);
                    cn_connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (r.Read())
                    {

                    }
                    cn_connection.Close();

                    load_list_zat();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create ListViewItem, you pass `id` there (then is is used as `Text` property).

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row["id"].ToString());
```

You can access it via SelectedItems property of ListView:

```
var id = "";
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    id = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

Comment: Yeah this would work but it only deletes 1 item..
With my solution you can select multiple items and delete them

Comment: Sure, but you can iterate through SelectedItems: `foreach (ListViewItem selectedItem in listView1.SelectedItems)`

Comment: It is also (when SelectedItems.Count < Items.Count) faster to iterate through SelectedItems, as you will loop only the same times as is the count of selected items

Comment: Okay, but i am not aiming for speed here xD its my first winforms project so yeah...